# passing the result of a void function to a double function

Tags: java, arrays, function, parameters, median

I am trying to merge two sorted arrays in a void function 'merged' then pass the merged array from that function to 'findMedianSortedArray' to find the median of that merged array.

I am having trouble figuring out how to do this and have exhausted my search via google. how would I be able to do this? thanks for your help.

Code below

```
class Solution {
    public double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2){ 
        int[] mergedArr = new int[nums1.length+nums2.length];
        double median;
        
        if(mergedArr.length %2 == 0 ){
            median = (mergedArr[mergedArr.length/2]+ mergedArr[mergedArr.length/2 - 1] ) /2;
        }else{
            median = mergedArr[mergedArr.length/2];
        }
        
        return median;
    }
    
    private void merged(int[] nums1, int[] nums2, int[] mergedArr){
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
       
        while(i < nums1.length && j < nums2.length){
            if(nums1[i]< nums2[j]){
                mergedArr[k] = nums1[i];
                i++;
            }else{
                mergedArr[k] = nums2[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while(i < nums1.length ){
            mergedArr[k] = nums1[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        while(j < nums2.length ){
            mergedArr[k] = nums2[j];
            i++;
            j++;
            
        }
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] your `merged` code is broken. It doesn't increment `k` in the second and third `while` loop.

[2] Just.. call it:

```
int[] mergedArr = new int[nums1.length+nums2.length];
merged(nums1, nums2, mergedArr);
```

The first line makes a new array, with nothing in it yet (all zeroes). The second line invokes the `merged` method, passing it all 3 arrays. The way your `merged` method works, is that it sets the values of the third array. Which is your `mergedArr`, so once `merged` returns, it'll have what you want.

Ordinarily you'd instead write a method that returns `int[]`, and have the `merged` method *make* that array. Your title is effectively an oxymoron: A `void` function, by definition, doesn't return anything. You've gone for the creative choice to have a method that modifies one of its arguments. It works; it's not exactly a modern coding style.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I was over thinking this massively upon reflection.